# How to stop session of unity ARKIT?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit

I have integrated Unity Arkit plugin in existing ios i am facing issue of battery and heat up on app . Now i want the stop the session of unity ARKIT and start when required. Right now it only pause ARKIT and camera still tracking in the pause state.

Please provide me any method which stop and start the session of UnityArkit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public void planeDetectionOn () {
        ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration config = new ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration ();
        config.planeDetection = UnityARPlaneDetection.Horizontal;
        config.alignment = UnityARAlignment.UnityARAlignmentGravity;
        config.getPointCloudData = true;
        config.enableLightEstimation = true;
        m_session.RunWithConfig (config);
        isDetecting = true;
    }

    public void planeDetectionOff () {
        ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration config = new ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration ();
        config.planeDetection = UnityARPlaneDetection.None;
        config.alignment = UnityARAlignment.UnityARAlignmentGravity;
        config.getPointCloudData = false;
        config.enableLightEstimation = false;
        m_session.RunWithConfig (config);
        isDetecting = false;
    }
```

This restarts the session configuration. I put it in my script that manages m_session. Example of such script from the plugin is UnityARCameraManager. Instead of RunWithConfig you can also use RunWithConfigAndOptions depending on your needs. Options are:

```
public enum UnityARSessionRunOption {
        /** The session will reset tracking. */
        ARSessionRunOptionResetTracking           = (1 << 0),

        /** The session will remove existing anchors. */
        ARSessionRunOptionRemoveExistingAnchors   = (1 << 1)
    }
```

From the README.md in UnityARKitPlugin:

```
    public void RunWithConfigAndOptions(ARKitWorldTackingSessionConfiguration config, UnityARSessionRunOption runOptions)

    public void RunWithConfig(ARKitWorldTackingSessionConfiguration config)
```

There is also a method

```
public void Pause()
```

but I haven't tried myself what exactly it does.